# after removing attribute button is still perfoming actions in jQuery

Tags: jquery

It's kinda simple piece of code, so i won't explain what it does.

Problem here is after I click the `.likes.1` div and then clicking `.likes.2` div and then again `.likes.1` it ends up showing me the `.article-info` div.

So even the attribute surname removed it stills perform it's task.

Why is that so ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".likes.1[surname|='first']").click(function() {
        generate('information');
        $(this).removeAttr('surname');
        $(".article-info").show();
    });

    $(".likes.2").click(function() {
        $(".article-info").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding of the click event happens on page load, or more accurately on DOM ready.

```
$(".likes.1[surname|='first']").click(function() { ... })
```

This binds the event to any and all elements that match that selector on pageload, removing an attribute, class, ID or anything else related to that selector at a later time will not change that, as the event is already bound.

You'll need to unbind the event or use a delegated event handler, as a delegated handler will check the selector on every click:

```
$(document).on("click", ".likes.1[surname|='first']", function() { ... })
```

You should use the closest available parent to the targeted element instead of document (and a class consisting of just a number is generally not a good idea).

or something like :

```
$(".likes.1[surname|='first']").on('click', function() {
    generate('information');
    $(this).off('click');
    $(".article-info").show();
});
```

Comment: +1, though using such a complicated delegation selector bound directly to the document may reduce the page's performance.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - You're right, added at least a comment to replace document with the closest parent to make the event handler "narrower".